# Minimize with constraints on parameters does not stop running

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I have the following simple optimization problem, but when I tried to put the values into Mathmatica, it does not stop running for hours.

Actual problem is:

$\qquad min_{x1, x2, x3} : a1\,x1 + a2\,x2 + a3\,x3$

subject to

$\qquad a1\,x1 + a2\,x2 + a3\,x3 - d >= b1\,x1 + b2\,x2 + b3\,x3$

$\qquad x1,\,x2,\,x3 \geq 0$

and this problem also has the constraint on parameters:

$\qquad a1 + a2 + a3 = 1$

$\qquad b1 + b2 + b3 =1$

$\qquad a1, b1, b2, b3 > 0$

$\qquad a2, a3 \geq 0, d>0$

$\qquad a3/b3 > a2/b2 > a1/b1$

the code I tried for is the following:

```
$Assumptions = a1 >0; $Assumptions = b1 >0; $Assumptions = b2 >0;
$Assumptions = b3 >0; $Assumptions = a2 >=0; $Assumptions = a3 >=0;
$Assumptions = d>0; $Assumptions =  a1 + a2 + a3 =1;
$Assumptions = b1 + b2 + b3 =1;  $Assumptions = a3/b3> a2/b2;
$Assumptions = a2/b2> a1/b1;

Minimize[
  {a1 * x1 + a2 * x2 + a3 * x3, 
   a1 * x1 + a2 * x2 + a3 * x3 - d >= 
     b1 * x1 + b2 * x2 + b3 * x3 && x1 >= 0 && 
   x2 >= 0 && x3 >= 0}, 
  {x, y}]
```

This looks to mr like a pretty straight forward linear programming style optimization problem, but Mathmatica does not stop running for hours.

I am new to Mathmatica and would greatly appreciate any insight.

Comment: You reset `$Assumptions` everytime you reuse it with an `=` sign.

Comment: Use `And` (`&&`) to join conditions.

Comment: ... and `LinearProgramming`, not `Minimize` (which does not pay attention to `$Assumptions` anyway).

Comment: and `a1+a2+a3 ==1` and `b1+b2+b3==1`

Comment: In addition to there being a mismatch of variables, this is not a n LP problem. Thea_j are variables as much as are the x_j.